# AlertDialog inside service not moving up when showing keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-service, android-alertdialog

I have a floating app that is run in a service. To make dialog inside a service you have to set its type to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT this works and the dialog shows. My only problem is that when I have an editText inside this alert dialog the keyboard shows up but the dialog does not move. So the keyboard will block some parts of the dialog.

I have searched answers here on stackOverflow but can't find any that works. I have tried adding SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN on the dialog but no results.

Any ideas how I can move the dialog? I know the Facebook messenger app floating bubble does this.

Here is my custom AlertDialog:

```
    public class ServiceDialogBuilder extends android.app.AlertDialog.Builder {

    public ServiceDialogBuilder(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public AlertDialog create() {
        AlertDialog dialog = super.create();

        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public AlertDialog show()   {
        return super.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` doesn't re-position starting from API 19.
Try using `TYPE_PHONE` instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`

Comment: Wow thanks! Dialog now moves. now I have a new problem, my floating view is now on top of the AlertDialog.

Comment: Ok solved it by using TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR instead of TYPE_PHONE or TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, I put

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

in the block before showing the dialog or in the onCreateDialog callback